# dictionary changed size during iteration, after deepcopy, python

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy

I have a list, which I copied using deepcopy. In a function above, I have another list that also uses deep copy and works as expected. Although for the code below, I get a RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration. Not sure why this is happening as I'm copying the original list and then running modifications on the copied list. The data object, are dictionaries within a list.

```
amdcount = 0
with open('amd3.json', 'r') as b:
    data = json.load(b)
    newlist.append(data)

copylist = copy.deepcopy(new_list)
for item in copylist:
    for k in item:
        if k == 'minute':
            item['test'] = 'test'
            print(k, item[k])
```

The above code generates a RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `item['test'] = 'test'` you're modifying the `item` dictionary while you're iterating over it with `for k in item:`

You can make a copy of the dictionary keys with `list(item)`:

```
for k in list(item):
    if k == 'minute':
        item['test'] = 'test'
        print(k, item[k])
```

It's not clear why you need the loop at all, though. It can just be

```
if 'minute' in item:
    item['test'] = 'test'
    print('minute', item['minute'])
```

Comment: The inner loop isn't even needed as the following as the same effect: `if 'minute' in item: item['test'] = 'test'; print('minute', item['minute'])`

Comment: @DanD. I agree, but I assumed this was a simplification of something that has more cases and might actually need the loop.

Comment: Although they could probably just be multiple `if 'xxx' in item:` tests.

Comment: Which one is better: (**a**) `for k in item.keys(): ...` or, (**b**) `for k in list(item): ...`? I think `item.keys()` is more verbose. But is there any difference in speed?

Comment: You'll get the same error if you use `item.keys()`, because it uses a generator.

Comment: hey Barmar, I was able to get it working. Thanks a lot, saved me a ton of headache.